# Adding item to an Array 2D

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, syntax, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to add an Item to an Array 2d.

But this throws an exception with message like this: `Redim only can change the dimension which is more to the right`

```
' Create Array 2D

Dim MyArray As String(,) = _
{{"Item 0,0", "Item 0,1"}, {"Item 1,0", "Item 1,1"}, {"Item 2,0", "Item 2,1"}}


' Add Item

ReDim Preserve MyArray(MyArray.GetUpperBound(0)+1, MyArray.GetUpperBound(1)+1)
MyArray(MyArray.GetUpperBound(0), MyArray.GetUpperBound(1) - 1) = "Item 3,0"
MyArray(MyArray.GetUpperBound(0), MyArray.GetUpperBound(1)) = "Item 3,1"
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Also... I could set the two dimensions at the same time like this?:

```
ReDim Preserve MyArray(MyArray.GetUpperBound(0)+1, MyArray.GetUpperBound(1)+1)
MyArray(lastitem) = {"Item 3,0", "Item 3,1"}
```

> UPDATE:

Well... trying it otherwise, I don't get it, the code does not work:

```
' Add Item

Dim MyArray2(MyArray.GetUpperBound(0) + 1, MyArray.GetUpperBound(1) + 1)(,) As String
MyArray.CopyTo(MyArray2, 0)
MyArray2(MyArray2.GetUpperBound(0), MyArray2.GetUpperBound(1) - 1) = "Item 3,0"
MyArray2(MyArray2.GetUpperBound(0), MyArray2.GetUpperBound(1)) = "Item 3,1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the [ReDim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) documentation:-

> **Resizing with Preserve.** If you use **Preserve**, you can resize only the
>   last dimension of the array, and for every other dimension you must
>   specify the same bound it already has in the existing array.
>
> For example, if your array has only one dimension, you can resize that
>   dimension and still preserve all the contents of the array, because
>   you are changing the last and only dimension. However, if your array
>   has two or more dimensions, you can change the size of only the last
>   dimension if you use Preserve.

So to resize the array in more than one dimension, you would need something like this:-

```
Dim second_array(my_array.GetUpperBound(0) + 1, my_array.GetUpperBound(1) + 1) As String

For i As Integer = 0 To my_array.GetUpperBound(0)
    For j As Integer = 0 To my_array.GetUpperBound(1)
        second_array(i,j) = my_array(i,j)
    Next j
Next i

my_array = second_array
```

Comment: Thanks for the information but the problem is not solved, I still have no idea of how to fix it, please see my update if you could.

Comment: @ElektroStudios, you are quite right; I've added a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you determine you need a larger array than you already have, you will need to define a new array rather than ReDim the existing one if the first dimension changes, then copy across all the contents.

Array(2,2) -> Array(2,4) 'ReDim will work for this.
Array(2,2) -> Array(4,2) 'Create a new array and copy the contents

Comment: thnaks but ...and how I do that?... sorry I need more help than a `Create a new array and copy contents` because I don't know how to fix it, I'm trying to write a generic function to add an item to a 2D array then I need to automatize arraybound calculations and those things. please see my update if you could.